# Выделение слова "шире" запятыми

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Надо ли выделить «шире»? «Очевидно в этом понятии отложились общие для индоиранских и(,) шире(,) индоевропейских народов представления».

Comment: После "очевидно" ещё запятую забыли.

Answer (score 2):

Запятыми слово/словосочетание отделается тогда, когда его можно убрать без потери смысла.

Здесь слово `шире` вводное и отделяется с двух сторон запятыми.

Ещё нужна запятая после `Очевидно`, так как это тоже вводное слово.